# Cannot download nvm install v.8.9.1 version - clang checksum do not match, sed issue

Tags: npm, node-modules, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install node version v8.9.1.  This is because I specifically need this version for Hyperledger Fabric to work correctly, according to [this thread on github issues](http://tps://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2714).

```
Downloading and installing node v8.9.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.1/node-v8.9.1-darwin-x64.tar.xz...


Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums do not match: '\ed71abc42e00f9d1f55f0977ff55cad2f68f3e8693211d33922d9286e6f6540b' found, 'ed71abc42e00f9d1f55f0977ff55cad2f68f3e8693211d33922d9286e6f6540b' expected.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 4 CPU core(s)
Running with 3 threads to speed up the build
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.1/node-v8.9.1.tar.xz...######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums do not match: '\ef160c21f60f8aca64145985e01b4044435e381dc16e8f0640ed0223e84f17e0' found, 'ef160c21f60f8aca64145985e01b4044435e381dc16e8f0640ed0223e84f17e0' expected.
akhs-MacBook-Pro:fabric-tools akh$ nvm ls
sed: 2: "
        s#/Users/a ...": unterminated substitute pattern
        N/A
sed: 2: "
        s#/Users/a ...": unterminated substitute pattern
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
sed: 2: "
        s#/Users/a ...": unterminated substitute pattern
sed: 2: "
        s#/Users/a ...": unterminated substitute pattern
iojs -> N/A (default)
sed: 2: "
        s#/Users/a ...": unterminated substitute pattern
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.7 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.13.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.10.0 (-> N/A)
```

Comment: nevermind. I did a clean uninstall of node and used nvm, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

User did a clean uninstall of node - and used NVM - cool.